# Lambda expression Any returns wrong value

Tags: c#, lambda, any

I have this lambda expression:

```
if (!myList.Any( x => x.name == "example" && x.articleNumber == "1"))
{

}
else
{

}
```

myList contains an object from the class which has these properties: articleNumber, name and quantity.

And this enters in the if instead of in the else althought there is an object with name "example" AND articleNumber "1". Why does this happen?

Comment: What are the contents of myList?

Comment: if you **don't** have an entry with name *example* and acticleNumber *1* it **should** go into the if block.

Comment: Because no elements of `myList` match the predicate? If you think something *should* match, I'd check again. (The debugger will be your friend here and you can iterate through the list if you'd like)

Comment: What is in the list and what is your expected result? We can't tell you why without the scope.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Why do you use inverse logic? It makes for code that is more difficult to read.

Comment: Is article number a string?

Comment: Well, answer to a question is that `myList` doesn't contains any elements with `name` == example and `articleNumber` == 1. But I guess this isn't quite a good answer for you

Comment: @CR41G14 Yes it's a string.

Comment: @Gorpik How do you mean inverse logic?

Comment: Can you dump or print it's contents or write a unit test?

Comment: @petko_stankoski If you have code for both cases (`if` and `else`), the code is easier to read if you don't use a negative condition. Otherwise, your `else` happens when the condition is "not not" met, which is more difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason i can see is that there's no element with `name=="example"` and `articleNumber=="1"`. Note that the `==` operator is case sensitive in C# and that there might be a white-space somewhere.

Then you can use this [overload of `Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) to compare case-insensitive  and remove white-spaces with `Trim`:

```
if (!myList.Any( x => x.name.Trim().Equals("example", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                   && x.articleNumber == "1"))
{

}
else
{

}
```

You should also consider to change the type of `articleNumber` to `int` since it is a number.

Answer (score 4):

You are aware of the `!` before your lamda right?

what you are asking in the if statement is

If myList does NOT contain any values where name is example AND article number is 1

I don't know if this helps but maybe it's easier to answer if you supply more information about what you want to accomplish with the statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the list don't contain the entry you think it does. Set a debug marker on the if line, and inspect the list at that point to see what it contains. You will find that the entry is not there. Remember that strings are case sensitive as well, so if name really is Example, it will not match.

Comment: It does not contain **exactly** that at least. Im sure that *Any* is not broken in suck a way.

Comment: So the most likely cancidates for it looks the same is a problem with case in the text "example", or some whitespace somewhere in one of the two strings.

Comment: If you still believe it contains the correct value, take a screenshot of the inspected list when debugging at the if statement, and post it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your list probably contains some values that you don't expect.

Try to replace `&&` with `||` and see what you will get:

```
var v = myList.Where(x => x.name == "example" || x.articleNumber == "1").ToList();
```

just to see what's there
.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your logic but you counld try??

```
if (myList.Where( x => x.name == "example").Where(x=> x.articleNumber == "1").Count() > 0)
{

}
else
{

}
```

OR to remove all spaces and variances in Casing

```
if (!myList.Any( x => x.name.Trim().ToLower() == "example" && x.articleNumber.Trim().ToLower() == "1"))
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Why would you complicate the if statement to produce the exact same result?

Answer (score -1):

The definition of Any:
Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.

So for each element in a sequence it is determined if the predicate is matching your expression.

```
myList.Any( x => x.name == "example" && x.articleNumber == "1")
```

Will return true if ANY element of the List has the name "example" AND the articleNumber 1.

```
!myList.Any( x => x.name == "example" && x.articleNumber == "1")
```

Will return true if NO element of the List has the name "example" AND the articleNumber 1.